# ping works but not telnet in putty

Tags: unix, ping, telnet

I am trying to ping one remote server. I am surprised that ping works but not telnet.

```
ping 174.25.366.25 --connection is successful.
```

where as

```
telnet 174.25.366.25 --connection timed out
```

I also want to check for connection on specific port

```
telnet 174.25.366.25 8090  ---connection timed out
```

Why is that difference and what does it convey

Comment: You should really think about switching to SSH. Telnet is completely insecure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well from what you say you got a port problem

1. your ISP might block the port
2. or you didn't forward the port

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am still not getting why ping works but not telnet. Can you help with that

Comment: @Patan because ping is using ICMP protocol and Telnet is using TCP/IP, typically port 23. Your server's IP is reachable, but it's not receiving port 23 connections because this port is either blocked or not forwarded.

Comment: @gronostaj. Here I am using port 8090. Even then it is getting refused. So can I assume that the port 8090 is blocked or not forwarded.

Comment: @Patan one more thing that comes to my mind is a firewall blocking that port.

Comment: here is a link that might be useful to for testing ports http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/